# can't pass php session variable to javascript string variable

Tags: php, javascript

Can't pass php session variable to javascript string variable

While the **$_SESSION['Id'] variable exists**, the javascript can't seem to bring it at least with this syntax:

**CODE**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<script>
var a = "<?php echo $_SESSION['Id']; ?>";
alert(a);
</script>
```

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump` `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Can you post your Javascript code? We need to see how you're trying to acquire that value.

Comment: PHP array indexes are case sensitive. Should Id be lowercase as id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, like the comments have mentioned, make sure you're using the correct case of id, whether it's `id` or `Id`.

Second, try using `json_encode` to convert it for javascript use. No need for `""`:

```
var a = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['Id']); ?>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax looks fine. What happens if you write this?

```
<?php
php session_start();

echo '<div style="padding:30px; background-color:#ffffff;"><pre>'.print_r($_SESSION, true).'</pre></div>';

?>

<script>
var a = "<?php echo $_SESSION['Id']; ?>";
alert(a);
</script>
```

If that doesn't work then try manually setting the ID before the echo

```
<?php
php session_start();

$_SESSION['Id'] = 'AN ID!!!';

echo '<div style="padding:30px; background-color:#ffffff;"><pre>'.print_r($_SESSION, true).'</pre></div>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if the variable $_SESSION['Id'] exists and is set to something

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    print_r( $_SESSION );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = "<?php echo $_SESSION['Id']; ?>";
  alert(a);
</script>
```